# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting this error,

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View
>   android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference"

Here is my code.

```
black.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View bView = findViewById(R.id.lin);
            View root = bView.getRootView();
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
    });
```

I have two views, one called overlay_view and the other activity_main. I am trying to change the color of overlay_view but I am getting this error. I have the setcontentView to activity_main, and if I switch it to overlay_view it does not give me a error. However I do not want to switch the setContentView to overlay_view so is there another way to do this? Thanks

Edit: 
I have a service which adds in overlay_view. The service is called from the mainactivity. Here is where it is called from in the main activity:

```
    public void sendMessage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrawOverAppsService.class);

    startService(intent);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
}
```

And here is the service:

```
public class DrawOverAppsService extends Service {

public static final String TAG = "DrawOverAppsService";



View mOverlayView;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    // An alpha value to apply to this entire window.
    // An alpha of 1.0 means fully opaque and 0.0 means fully transparent
    params.alpha = 0.1F;

    // When FLAG_DIM_BEHIND is set, this is the amount of dimming to apply.
    // Range is from 1.0 for completely opaque to 0.0 for no dim.
    params.dimAmount = 0.9F;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    mOverlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null);

    wm.addView(mOverlayView, params);





}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.removeView(mOverlayView);


}
}
```

This is the xml for overlay_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF4081"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you create a view in a service and want to reference it in the main activity to change its background color. Your line `View bView = findViewById(R.id.lin`) is giving you a null value because the system cannot find `R.id.lin` in `activity_main`. `R.id.lin` does exist in `overlay_view` and that is why you don't get the error with that view used in setContentView().

The service class variable `mOverlayView` has a reference to the view you want. I don't know of `findViewById()` functionality for views added via the window manager, so you will need to implement a connection between the activity and the service. The service code to change the background will look something like this:

```
View bView = mOverlayView.findViewById(R.id.lin);
if (bView != null) {}
    View root = bView.getRootView();
    root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
}
```

In the `onClick` handler of the activity, you will notify the service to change the background. There are several ways to handle this and you may already have a way to send commands to the service. If not, take a look at [startService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent))

> Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the target service's onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method, with the intent given here. This provides a convenient way to submit jobs to a service without having to bind and call on to its interface.

You can also set up a local broadcast manager or bind the service. Search for ["android activity service communication"](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+activity+service+communication&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for results on alternate ways to handle this.

You may also want to familiarize yourself with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796873/6287910) before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! lin is a linear layout in overlay_view, and overlay_view is the name of my second xml file. I am unsure if the view that is given as the argument to onClick is related, it was automatically put in when i was typing the code (I think you are talking about "View v"). I have a service which adds the overlay_view with special params to make it display transparent, and over top of all other things on screen. That is why I do not want to setContentView to overlay_view, because it loses its special params. I will edit my question with some more code since it is too long for here

Comment: @sandraburgle Closer. What is `black` and where is the `OnClickListener` set? You need to get a reference to `mOverlayView` that is set in your service so your `findViewById()` works. Since the service maintains the class variable `mOverlayView`, you could just request the service set the background color from within `onClick()`.

Comment: black is the id of the button. The OnClickListener is set in mainactivity. How would I set the background color in the service with onClick? By the way, thanks for taking the time and helping me so far I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: Thanks! I think this one will work. I am getting this error now : `06-27 15:58:29.803 1995-2861/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app 06-27 15:58:29.804 1995-2861/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?` Do I need to use a pending intent? I am using `public void changeBlack(){ Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChangeColor.class); startService(intent); }` and I am calling `changeBlack` with `onClick`. I feel your answer will work so I will accept it, thanks!

Comment: Oh, never mind, forget that comment above. I ran it again and `Unable to start service Intent U=0: not found` is the message. I found a solution here I think it will help me.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105587/unable-to-start-service-intent-not-found) Thanks again, I upvoted and accepted your answer.

Comment: @sandraburgle Your class name needs to be the class name of your service. Take another look at `startService()`. I think your answer is in the implementation of `onStartService()`. It is there that you should do your onClick processing. The intent will carry your instructions from the activity to the service.

Comment: @sandraburgle [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15899750/6287910) might help you.

Comment: Hey, I made a new post if you would like to check it out. I see what you meant with `onStartCommand`, it will really help me out down the road. Here is the new post, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787114/color-of-view-wont-change-programmatically)